# How to cross join in Excel VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I want to cross join two columns from a sheet and paste the result in another sheet using VBA.
[image]

Cross join of column A and B from Sheet1 and paste result into Sheet2.

[image]

I found two answers but not able to modify them to my need.

[Pure VBA function](https://superuser.com/a/650170)

[using PowerQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46957483)

**My need is,**

1. cross join of first two columns from a sheet with variable name (as I have to run it in a loop).
2. paste the result at end of another sheet.

***Edit: added requirement***
3. There will be multiple source sheet like "Sheet1" in a loop. I don't want to create table on every sheet.

Comment: With **MS365** ==> `=SORT(DROP(REDUCE("",TOCOL(A2:A5&"|"&TOROW(B2:B4)),LAMBDA(x,y,VSTACK(x,TEXTSPLIT(y,"|")))),1),2)`

Comment: With regard to your additional requirement added today, in Power Query you could use `Named Ranges` instead of tables. Although, in this forum, new problems should be posted as a new question once you have a solution to the problem you originally posted.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld really thanks for your answer. But am struggling to modify your answer. Can you please add another answer using named ranges. Also, can you suggest which approach will be best to use in a loop for multiple sheets??? 

Comment: @AyanBhunia The only modification you need to make is on the `Source =` line. Just replace the name of the table with the `Named Range`. And I don't think it makes much difference which approach you use.

Comment: @AyanBhunia If the file has been saved, you could get away with not using named ranges. Since the `Excel.Workbook` function can return worksheets. But then you'd have to also write a function to detect the relevant data on those worksheets.

Answer (score 5):

Pretty simple using power query.
Just add a column which contains a ***List*** of all the non-null entries in the  **value** column; then expand to new rows. Finally Sort back to the desired order.

Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

```
let

//change next line to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],

//set data types to text
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"name", type text}, {"value", type text}}),

//add index column so as to be able to sort back to desired output
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),

//Add a column containing a List of all non-null Values
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "values", each List.RemoveNulls(#"Added Index"[value])),

//remove now unneeded value column
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"value"}),

//expand the List to new rows
    #"Expanded values" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Removed Columns", "values"),

//Sort back to original order
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Expanded values",{{"values", Order.Ascending}, {"Index", Order.Ascending}}),

    #"Removed Index" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Sorted Rows",{"Index"}),
    #"Type Values" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Index",{{"values", type text}})
in
    #"Type Values"
```

***Original***
[image]

***Result***
[image]